# How do you map attribute names using MagicalRecord?

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

I have an NSManagedObjectModel subclass, and it has this property:

`userId`

However, the downloaded XML, which is parsed into an `NSDictionary` to be mapped to my model, uses this property:

`userid`

(Note the difference in case)

I tried following this blog post, yet I'm still doing something wrong (because the data doesn't map correctly):

http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/

Here's a screenshot showing how I setup the model in the data model builder:

[image: Screen Shot, MagicalRecord]

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the correct way to do this:

On the attribute set this:

`name = userId`

On the attribute's `User Info` set these:

```
key = mappedKeyName
value = userid
```

Here's how it should look:

[image: MagicalRecord Mapping Setup]